# Swift Package Manager - Unexpected duplicate tasks: Target AppTests (project App) has copy command - SwiftDate

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, swiftdate

I'm migrating my project from Carthage to SPM. I'm using Xcode 12.0. Building the main app works without any problems but I cannot run my unit tests anymore. I use the same framework [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) v6.2.0 in both my App target (SPMD) and my App test target (SPMDTests).

I already resolved the `Swift package product 'your library' is linked as a static library by 'your project' and 'your widget'. This will result in duplication of library code.`. I followed the tutorial [Swift Package Manager Static Dynamic Xcode Bug](https://github.com/renaudjenny/Swift-Package-Manager-Static-Dynamic-Xcode-Bug).

I can run my app but I cannot run my unit tests. The error says

```
Unexpected duplicate tasks:
1) Target 'SPMDTests' (project 'SPMD') has copy command from 'xxx/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate_SwiftDate.bundle' to 'xxx/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SPMD.app/PlugIns/SPMDTests.xctest/SwiftDate_SwiftDate.bundle'
2) Target 'SPMDTests' (project 'SPMD') has copy command from 'xxx/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate_SwiftDate.bundle' to 'xxx/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SPMD.app/PlugIns/SPMDTests.xctest/SwiftDate_SwiftDate.bundle'
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image]

I tried the same setup with *Realm* and it works without any problems. Is this a bug with *SwiftDate* or am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you solve this issue yet?

Comment: 2021, and I just ran into this. Any luck yet? Maybe the latest XCode beta doesn't have this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in the implementation of Swift Packages that include resources in Xcode 12 (also in Xcode 12.2 beta).

This issue will only arise if you have a dependency on a package that has resources (SwiftDate does) in both your main target and your unit test target. This bug only seems to affect compilation of the unit test target, so the main app target should still compile successfully.

Comment: Yes, it only affects my unit test target. Do you know if an official bug report exists?

Comment: I've opened a feedback report (FB8751233) a few days ago, so far there has been no response. I believe this is a bug in the "new build system" in Xcode and how it has implemented handling of swift packages that contain resources, so I did not open a bug report on the open source project bug tracker.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a way to workaround it?

Comment: I haven't found a way to work around the issue, and I'm not sure there is one, other than to copy all your code into one package. Since you're encountering the same issue, I would suggest that you also open a bug report with Apple (using Feedback Assistant) as more feedback reports help the issue gain visibility at Apple.

Comment: Just relying on SO as well, we're seeing the same problem, and have filed both a radar and https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13739

Comment: I also opened a feedback, no response yet from Apple.